# Python Selenium Webdriver: Unable to load all reviews on the browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to extract all google reviews of a restaurant. There are just over 900 reviews of the restaurant. However, my script was only able to extract 50 reviews. I am not sure where am I making the mistake. Any help to fix the issue would be highly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
base_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:9&tbm=lcl&sxsrf=AOaemvJFjYToqQmQGGnZUovsXC1CObNK1g:1633336974491&q=10+famous+restaurants+in+Dunedin&rflfq=1&num=10&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTsqaxrrDzAhXe4zgGHZPODcoQjGp6BAgKEGo&biw=1280&bih=557&dpr=2#lrd=0xa82eac0dc8bdbb4b:0x4fc9070ad0f2ac70,1,,,&rlfi=hd:;si:5749134142351780976,l,CiAxMCBmYW1vdXMgcmVzdGF1cmFudHMgaW4gRHVuZWRpbiJDUjEvZ2VvL3R5cGUvZXN0YWJsaXNobWVudF9wb2kvcG9wdWxhcl93aXRoX3RvdXJpc3Rz2gENCgcI5Q8QChgFEgIIFkiDlJ7y7YCAgAhaMhAAEAEQAhgCGAQiIDEwIGZhbW91cyByZXN0YXVyYW50cyBpbiBkdW5lZGluKgQIAxACkgESaXRhbGlhbl9yZXN0YXVyYW50mgEkQ2hkRFNVaE5NRzluUzBWSlEwRm5TVU56ZW5WaFVsOUJSUkFCqgEMEAEqCCIEZm9vZCgA,y,2qOYUvKQ1C8;mv:[[-45.8349553,170.6616387],[-45.9156414,170.4803685]]'
driver.get(base_url)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[./span[text()='Newest']]"))).click()

title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='P5Bobd']").text
address = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='T6pBCe']").text
overall_rating = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='review-score-container']//span[@class='Aq14fc']").text
total_reviews_text =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='review-score-container']//div//div//span//span[@class='z5jxId']").text
 
num_reviews = int (total_reviews_text.split()[0])
all_reviews = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.gws-localreviews__google-review')))
total_reviews = len(all_reviews)

while total_reviews < num_reviews:
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', all_reviews[-1])
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 0.25).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class$="activityIndicator"]')))
        #all_reviews = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.gws-localreviews__google-review')
        all_reviews = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.gws-localreviews__google-review')))
        print(total_reviews)
        total_reviews +=1
```

Comment: Most likely the dom isn't loading tell you scroll over it, you could add some scrolling functions or you could use pyautogui and have it scroll manually tell it is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium expected condition `presence_of_all_elements_located` doesn't really wait for presence of ALL the elements matching the passed to that method locator.
It actually waits for at least 1 element matching the passed locator.
So instead of

```py
num_reviews = int (total_reviews_text.split()[0])
all_reviews = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.gws-localreviews__google-review')))
total_reviews = len(all_reviews)
```

Please try this:

```py
num_reviews = int (total_reviews_text.split()[0])
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.gws-localreviews__google-review')))
time.sleep(2)
all_reviews = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.gws-localreviews__google-review')
total_reviews = len(all_reviews)
```

Possibly you will have the same issue with the second use of `presence_of_all_elements_located` as well.
Generally, never trust `presence_of_all_elements_located`, it will give you the first caught matches only.

Comment: I changed value of 3 to 20 and inserted time.sleep but still the same result. It did not go over 53 reviews

Comment: maybe you need to scroll there as mentioned by Stefan?

Answer (score 1):

If you notice the reviews are lazy-loaded as you scroll. You may need to add some code to scroll down and wait for all the reviews to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below:

Was able to extract more than 50 of the reviewer names.

```
i = 0
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(.5)
        reviews = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='reviewSort']//div[contains(@class,'google-review')]")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",reviews[i])
        print(f"{i+1}:{reviews[i].find_element_by_xpath('./div/div/div/a').text}")
        i+=1
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass
```